# Converting integer to datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following two columns that I want to convert to datetime type of variable.

[image: original dataframe]

and after using the code shown in the picture below

[image: original df after the conversion to datetime]

I am getting something completely wrong. I have looked into different methods with no luck. Is there an alternative way to simply get a date column in the form of 8/24/2019?

Comment: Yes it's possible if you give the date for the value 0 (the origin)

Comment: please don't post images of data/code, edit your question to provide **text**

Comment: FYI, many systems (e.g. Unix) stored "date/time" values as a 32-bit unsigned integer, the #/seconds since an ["epoch"](https://www.epochconverter.com/) (Jan 1, 1970).  It looks like that's similar to what you're doing (either deliberately, or inadvertantly). Q: what exactly are you TRYING to do?

Comment: Assuming those dates are meant to be recent, it's probably a count of days since the year 1900.

Comment: @paulsm4 - I am trying to convert the integers (as shown in the first screenshot) to full dates such as 8/24/2019. When I am using the commands on the second screenshot it yields a result of 1970-01-01 00:00:00:000044463 which I cannot explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use `format` argument of `pandas.to_datetime()` function, there you can provide your format of datetime data as a `str` and pandas will use it for parsing.

Take a look at the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [syntax details](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) for `format` argument.